# mongoose callback is not an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my models I have this

```
module.exports.getPhotosById = function(userId,callback){
    Photos.findOne({userId:userId},callback);
}
```

Then in route I do

```
 Photo.getPhotosById(req.user._id,function(err,result){

    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.length);
  });
```

The first console output this

```
{ _id: 325657865435643245,
  userId: '32443564',
  photo: 'abc.jpg',
  caption: 'abc'
}
```

but why it's not an array? because the second console's output is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is a single document instead of an array because you're calling `findOne`, not `find`.

To get all of a user's photo docs, change your method to:

```
module.exports.getPhotosById = function(userId, callback){
    Photos.find({userId: userId}, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**findone** Returns one document(JSON) that satisfies the specified query criteria

**find** Returns the array of Objects.